# How to generate coverage for multiple packages using go test in custom folders?

Tags: unit-testing, go

We have following project structure:

```
├── Makefile
├── ...
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── main.go
│   │   ├── models
│   │       ├── ...
│   │       └── dao.go
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── controllers
│   │       ├── ...
│   │       └── pingController.go
│   └── test
│       ├── all_test.go
│       ├── ...
│       └── controllers_test.go
└── vendor
    └── src
        ├── github.com
        ├── golang.org
        └── gopkg.in
```

I want to measure coverage of packages in src/app by tests in src/test. And currently generating coverage profile by running custom script that runs coverage for each package in app and then merges all coverage profiles into one file. Recently I heard that in go1.10 we are able to generate coverage for multiple packages.

So I tried to replace that script with oneliner, and tried running

```
GOPATH=${PROJECT_DIR}:${PROJECT_DIR}/vendor go test -covermode count -coverprofile cover.out -coverpkg all ./src/test/...
```

It gives me "ok     test    0.475s  coverage: 0.0% of statements in all"

When I do

```
cd src/test/
GOPATH=${PROJECT_DIR}:${PROJECT_DIR}/vendor go test -covermode count -coverprofile cover.out -coverpkg all
```

Logs show that specs are runned and tests are successfull, but still I have "coverage: 0.0% of statements in all" and empty cover.out.

What am I missing to properly compute coverage of packages in app by tests in test?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535704/how-to-detect-code-coverage-of-separated-folders-in-go) might help. Basically in go it is not considered a good practice to have `tests` and `src` in separate packages

Comment: @Shettyh So, short answer is "not yet possible for this project structure"?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible as of now

Comment: It seems the `-coverpkg` option is fixed in recent versions of Go and correctly records coverage for packages listed there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't with the current state of `go test` but you can always use third party scripts.

https://github.com/grosser/go-testcov

Comment: It can be done, look at my reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/58508728/9361998

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```sh
go test -race -coverprofile=coverage.txt -covermode=atomic ./...  # Run all the tests with the race detector enabled
go test -bench=. -benchmem ./... # Run all the benchmark for 3s and print memory information
```

In order to create a test for a Go code, you have to create a file (in the same folder of the root code) that have the same name of the code, and append "_test" to the name. The package have to be the same too.

So, if I have a GO Code called `strings.go`, the relative test suite have to be named: `strings_test.go`.

After that, you have to create a method that have in input the `t *testing.T` 
struct, and the name of the method have to start with `Test` or `Benchmark` word.

So, if the `strings.go` contains a method called "IsUpper", the related test-case is a method called `TestIsUpper(t *testing.T)`.
If you need the Benchmark, than you need to substitute the `Test` word with `Benchmark`, so the name of the method will be `BenchmarkIsUpper`, and the struct that the method take in input is `b *testing.B`.

You can have a look at the following link in order to see the tree-structure necessary for execute the test in GO: https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoGPUtils.

There you can find Benchmark and TestCase.

Here an example of tree-struct

```
├── string
│   ├── stringutils.go
│   └── stringutils_test.go
```